# Simulation in python for Unique matches of demand supply using lists

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, simulation

I have data in the form of list of lists where I am trying to match the demand and supply such that each demand matches uniquely to one supply item.

```
dmndId_w_freq = [['a',4,[1,2,3,4]],['b',6,[5,6,7,8,3,4]],['c',7,[6,5,7,9,8,3,4]],['d',8,[1,6,3,4,5,6,7,10]]]
num_sims = 1
for sim_count in range(num_sims):
 dmndID_used_flag = {}
 splID_used_flag  = {}
 dmndID_splId_one_match = {}
 for i in dmndId_w_freq:
  if i[0] not in dmndID_used_flag.keys():
   for j in i[2]:
    #print j
    #print "CLICK TO CONTINUE..."
    #raw_input()
    if j in splID_used_flag.keys():
     i[2].remove(j)
  dmndID_splId_one_match[i[0]] =  i[2][0]
  splID_used_flag[i[2][0]] = 1
  dmndID_used_flag[i[0]] = 1
  print
  print dmndID_splId_one_match 
  #print splID_used_flag  
  #print dmndID_used_flag 
  #raw_input()
```

I would expect the output dmndID_splId_one_match to be something like {'a':1,'b':5,'c':6,'d':3}.
But I end up getting {'a':1,'b':5,'c':6,'d':6}
So I am NOT getting a unique match as the supply item 6 is getting mapped to demands 'c' as well as demand 'd'.
I tried to debug the code by looping through it and it seems that the problem is in the for-loop

```
for j in i[2]:
```

The code is not going through all the elements of i[2]. It does not happen with the 'a' and 'b' part. but starts happening with the 'c' part. It goes over 6 and 5 but skips 7 (the third element of the list [6,5,7,9,8,3,4]). Similarly, in the 'd' part it skips the 2nd element 6 in the list [1,6,3,4,5,6,7,10]. And that is why the mapping is happening twice, since I am not able to remove it.

1. What am I doing wrong that it is not executing the for-loop as expected?
2. Is there a better way to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem in the for loop. I am looping through i[2] and then trying to modify it within the loop. this makes it unstable.